# Regarding the new line characters .txt files contains when we are reading them in using the IO in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, for-loop, io

I am a beginner in Python and been playing around with what I know so far and came across the below problem. Can someone kindly help me out to understand why this occurs?

suppose I have a text named 'test.txt' file that contains the following,

```
This is the first line
This is the second line
This is the third line
```

I print every line in this text file by doing as below,

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

However though, the output we get is,

```
This is the first line

This is the second line

This is the third line
```

As shown above we get an empty line printed due to each line in the text file containing a '\n' at the end of the each line.

To get rid of the empty line that is printed above, I know we could do something like,

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line, end='')
```

This gives us the following output,

```
This is the first line
This is the second line
This is the third line
```

**What I do not understand is, how have we been able to get rid of the newline character just by adding an empty string to the end of each line?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that '\n' is the default parameter given to `end`.
This is from the official python docs:
`print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)`.
You can check the docs here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print

Answer (score 1):

The `print` function in python has a default value of `\n` for the parameter `end`, when you override that value by empty string `''` => `print(line, end='')` you remove the new line behavior.